# Python - Pandas, csv row iteration to divide by half based on criteria met

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I work with and collect data from the meters on the side of peoples houses in our service area. I worked on a python script to send high/low voltage alerts to my email whenever it occurs, but the voltage originally came in as twice what it actually was (So instead of 125V it showed 250V). So, I used pandas to divide the entire column by half.... Well, turns out a small handful of meters were programmed to send back the actual voltage of 125... So I can no longer halve the column and now must iterate and divide individually. I'm a bit new to scripting so my problem might be simple..

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvPath)
if "timestamp" not in df:
    df.insert(0, 'timestamp',currenttimestamp)
    for i in df['VoltageA']:
        if df['VoltageA'][i]>200:
            df['VoltageA'][i] = df['VoltageA'][i]/2
            df['VoltageAMax'][i] = df['VoltageAMax'][i]/2
            df['VoltageAMin'][i] = df['VoltageAMin'][i]/2
    df.to_csv(csvPath, index=False)
```

Timestamp is there just as a 'key' to avoid duplicate errors later in the same day.

Error I am getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 385, in get_loc
    return self._range.index(new_key)
ValueError: 250 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\script.py", line 139, in <module>
    updateTable(csvPath, tableName, truncate, email)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\script.py", line 50, in updateTable
    if df['VoltageA'][i]>200.0:
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 387, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 250.0
```

If this isn't enough and you actually need to see a csv snippet, let me know. Just trying not to put unnecessary info here. Note, the first VoltageA value is 250.0

Answer (score 1):

This example code below show how to use `loc` to conditionally change the value in multiple columns

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'voltageA': [190,230,250,100],
    'voltageMax': [200,200,200,200],
    'voltageMin': [100,100,100,100]
})

df.loc[df['voltageA'] > 200, ['voltageA', 'voltageMax', 'voltageMin']] = df.loc[df['voltageA'] > 200, ['voltageA', 'voltageMax', 'voltageMin']]/2 
df
```

Output

| voltageA | voltageMax | voltageMin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 190 | 200 | 100 |
| 115 | 100 | 50 |
| 125 | 100 | 50 |
| 100 | 200 | 100 |

The data in 2nd and 3rd row were divided by 2 because in the original data the value of `voltageA` in the two rows exceeds 200.

Comment: That did the trick! Very much appreciated.